# Moving an Object in a HTML5 Canvas with User Input

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, addeventlistener, keycode

I'm only new to JavaScript and I'm having a problem with my code where I'm trying to move an object around the canvas with user input.

It works just fine using Firefox to run it but with Chrome the user input to move the square doesn't work and I was wondering why this is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <canvas id = "gameCanvas" width="400" height="400" style = "border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
   <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";

    var snake = {
        x: 5
        , y: 5
      };


    function drawSnake() {
        ctx.fillRect(snake.x ,snake.y,20,20);
      }

    window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { 
        if (event.keyCode == 39)
          snake.x += 5;
        else if (event.keyCode == 37)
          snake.x -= 5;
        else if (event.keyCode == 38)
          snake.y -= 5;
        else if (event.keyCode == 40)
          snake.y += 5;

        drawSnake();
      });

   drawSnake();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Can you describe what does or does not happen in the way you expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your `keypress` event to `keydown` to make it work in IE and Chromium based browsers.